# What is the lowest interception point in the WCF runtime stack?

Tags: .net, wcf, message

I wish to debug why my application sends so much data using WCF underneath. I tried to examine WCF trace logs and examine the traffic with Fiddler, but I need a stack trace leading to the offending client code.

So, I installed a custom `IClientMessageInspector`, but how can I know the size of the actual data given a `Message` instance? The `ToString()` of the given `Message` instance returns an XML, but I am not sure if its size is it.

Is there a way to hook into the WCF stack even deeper and closer to the actual sending of the message?

**UPDATE**

Found this SO question 1 year old, funny, but no one answered it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457683/message-size-after-serialize

Comment: can you to add a behavior to your host, not your client?

Comment: Yes I can, I started with the client, but I can do the same with the server.

Comment: Sending big messages results with exception on the client side? This exception has a stack trace, isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes it does, so I want two thinks - reproduction during debugging and at the same time examine the message. I can get the former by stopping on the exception and the latter by examining the svclog file, but to combine the two in one debugging session I use WCF extension points. Besides, server side message inspection is of interest as well (I know how to do it with IDispatcherMessageInterceptor)

Answer (score 1):

You mention the *trace* logs - but have you enabled *message* logging? With this in place, you should have clear visibility of the underlying messages, so you should be able to see *exactly* what data is on the wire?

Comment: I also want stack trace, live preferably.

Comment: @mark - but at what point? You mention the message size - that is a transport concern, not a client / server concern...?

Comment: Thanks for clarification, is there a way to hook into the transport and see what is being transferred exactly? Or is IClientMessageInspector and IDispatchMessageInspector enough? Though, I cannot figure out how to get the length of the given Message instance...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the message interceptor, however note that "the body of a message can only be consumed ... once" (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createbufferedcopy.aspx)).

In essence you need to use `Message.CreateBufferedCopy()` to create a copy of the message to deal with as you like, including calling ToString() to dump it somewhere.

Also, when message interceptors are chained, you might not see the original message, but rather the one that the previous interceptor has created / altered.

So, if you really just want to see what is on the wire, you're probably better off with the builtin [WCF tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx), as Marc already said.

Comment: I am aware of the tracing facility, but I want to examine the actual message during a live debugging session.